# Which is the best practice using puppeteer to create pdf?

Tags: node.js, docker, pdf, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to create pdf from HTML template. Which approach is best practice in two solutions below?

1.Always launch puppeteer and create a new **browser** to create pdf. The **browser** will be **closed** when created pdf is done.

```
(async () => {
  const finalHtml = 'html content...';
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.pages()[0];
  await page.setContent(finalHtml);
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

2.Keep 1 instance **browser**. Always create a new **page** to create pdf. The **page** will be **closed** when created pdf is done

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

(async () => {
  const finalHtml = 'html content...';
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(finalHtml);
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});
  await page.close();
})();
```

Thank advance.

**Edited 1:** Also, what is the pros and cons of the two solutions above?

Comment: Can you share more context where you want to this code? There are at least hundreds things to consider when such opinion based question arrives :D

Comment: I want to compare performance: memory, cpu, ...

Comment: Finding the "best" requires a context. How do you define what's best? The one with least memory/cpu? I suggest you provide an example usage case of where you want to create the PDF and how many PDF you are talking about etc.

Comment: I did experiment with it last year, so I can somewhat provide you with benchmark but my doubt is in the "best". :D

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher What is the pros and cons of the two solutions above?

Comment: IMO, The only pro and con you will have is with sessions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Short Lived Browser (Opening new browser instance every time)

Pros:

- A new session opens each time, one instance doesn't interfere with another.
- Perfect for testing multiple credentials over same/multiple websites.
- Can use instance wide proxy.

Cons:

- You cannot share data between two instance easily (unless you use `userDataDir` or `cookies`).
- Takes more time to open.

## Long Lived Browser (Sharing same browser instance every time)

Pros:

- Opening a new tab takes way less time than opening a new chrome with empty profile.
- Data is shared between two instance easily. Perfect for scraping/testing same website with same credentials.

Cons:

- You won't be able to use authentication and cookies on same website using different credentials.
- Cannot use instance wide proxy (at this momemt).

## Benchmark

Here is a benchmark for running only 100 times.

The code to run:

```
const bench = require("@entrptaher/async-bench");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const createNewBrowser = async function() {
  const finalHtml = "html content...";
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(finalHtml);
  await page.pdf({ path: "hn_shortlived.pdf", format: "A4" });
  await browser.close();
  return true;
};

let longLivedBrowser;
const useExisting = async function() {
  const finalHtml = "html content...";
  if (!longLivedBrowser) {
    longLivedBrowser = await puppeteer.launch();
  }
  const page = await longLivedBrowser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(finalHtml);
  await page.pdf({ path: "hn_longlived.pdf", format: "A4" });
  await page.close();
  return true
};

let longLivedNoNewTab;
const useExitingTab = async function() {
  const finalHtml = "html content...";
  if (!longLivedNoNewTab) {
    longLivedNoNewTab = await puppeteer.launch();
  }
  const page = (await longLivedNoNewTab.pages())[0];
  await page.setContent(finalHtml);
  await page.pdf({ path: "hn_longlived.pdf", format: "A4" });
  return true
};

const times = 100;

Promise.all([
  bench(createNewBrowser, times),
  bench(useExisting, times),
  bench(useExitingTab, times)
]).then(console.log);
```

The result:

```
[ { meanExecTime: 277.3644104500115,
    execTime: 27736.44104500115,
    resultOfMethod: true },
  { meanExecTime: 36.89182792000472,
    execTime: 3689.1827920004725,
    resultOfMethod: true },
  { meanExecTime: 11.07780257999897,
    execTime: 1107.780257999897,
    resultOfMethod: true } ]
```

Each has following:

- `meanExecTime`: Average time to run
- `execTime`: Total time to run
- `resultOfMethod`: Just some result for identification

The benchmark is incomplete because it doesn't have the machine details etc. But it definitely shows that opening browser each time will result in more time, even if it's only 100 times.

On second function, you will also notice opening a new tab takes time, so on third function if you don't close the page, it will take even less time.

## Summary:

- If you need performance (11ms compared to 277ms), don't care about session, go for existing tab.
- If you want to run multiple test on same window in parallel, go for new tab.
- If you need sessions and persistence, go for new browser instance.

Comment: Nice. Thank advance. I need performance that why I will choose longLivedNoNewTab.

Comment: What is the link github of package async-bench? I can't find this package. Thanks

Comment: You can do `yarn add @entrptaher/async-bench` :)